Polars make all groups the same size
Question
I'm trying to make all groups for a given data frame have the same size. In Starting point below, I show an example of a data frame that I whish to transform. In Goal I try to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve. I want to group by the column group, make all groups have a size of 4, and fill 'missing' values with null - I hope it's clear.
I have tried several approaches but have not been able to figure this one out.
Starting point
dfa = pl.DataFrame(data={'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                         'value': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1']})
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    │
│ a     ┆ a2    │
│ a     ┆ a3    │
│ b     ┆ b1    │
│ b     ┆ b2    │
│ c     ┆ c1    │
└───────┴───────┘

Goal
>>> make_groups_uniform(dfa, group_by='group', group_size=4)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    │
│ a     ┆ a2    │
│ a     ┆ a3    │
│ a     ┆ null  │
│ b     ┆ b1    │
│ b     ┆ b2    │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ c1    │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘

Package version
polars: 1.1.0

Is it assumed that you'll never ask for a group_size that is smaller than any actual group_size? For example, if a had 5 entries, and you specify a group size of 4 should it error or take the first 4, last 4?

If you want to use dynamic group size as in your solution - you can do it more concise and probably more performant - see my answer below.

The advantage of the approach below is that we don’t transform original DataFrame (except maybe sorting if you want to rearrange the groups), we only create additional rows and append them back to the original DataFrame.

I've adjusted my answer a bit, based on assumption that you want size of the group to be max of the size of all groups, but it works as well for fixed group_size.

group_by() allows per-group calculation.
len() to determine size of the group.
repeat_by() creates lists based on previously calculated group size and max() group size.
filter() to filter out empty lists for case when we don't need to add extra rows.
explode() lists into column.
concat() back to existing DataFrame.
(optional) sort() if you need groups to be together.

# you can use fixed group_size instead of pl.col.len.max() as well

pl.concat([
    dfa,
    (
        dfa.group_by("group").len()
        .select(pl.col.group.repeat_by(pl.col.len.max() - pl.col.len))
        .filter(pl.col.group.list.len() != 0)
        .explode("group")
    )
], how="diagonal").sort("group")

shape: (9, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    │
│ a     ┆ a2    │
│ a     ┆ a3    │
│ b     ┆ b1    │
│ b     ┆ b2    │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ c1    │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘

If you need fixed group size, then repeat() is probably more performant, but the idea is the same - only generate additional rows and append them back to original DataFrame.
group_size = 3

# you can make it dynamic as well though
# group_size = dfa.group_by("group").len().max()["len"].item()

pl.concat([
    dfa,
    (
        dfa.group_by("group")
        .agg(value = pl.repeat(None, group_size - pl.len().cast(int)))
        .filter(pl.col.value.list.len() != 0)
        .explode("value")
    )
]).sort("group")

shape: (9, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    │
│ a     ┆ a2    │
│ a     ┆ a3    │
│ b     ┆ b1    │
│ b     ┆ b2    │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ c1    │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘


You could use pl.repeat() to generate the nulls and .append() them.
group_size = 4

(df.group_by("group", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(pl.all().append(pl.repeat(None, group_size - pl.len().cast(int))))
   .explode(pl.exclude("group"))
) 

Or, you can use pl.len().over("group").max() to calculate the largest group size.
(df.with_columns(group_size=pl.len().over("group").max())
   .group_by("group", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(pl.all().append(pl.repeat(None, pl.col("group_size") - pl.len().cast(int))))
   .explode(pl.exclude("group"))
) 

shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ value ┆ group_size │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ u32        │
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    ┆ 3          │
│ a     ┆ a2    ┆ 3          │
│ a     ┆ a3    ┆ 3          │
│ b     ┆ b1    ┆ 3          │
│ b     ┆ b2    ┆ 3          │
│ b     ┆ null  ┆ null       │
│ c     ┆ c1    ┆ 3          │
│ c     ┆ null  ┆ null       │
│ c     ┆ null  ┆ null       │
└───────┴───────┴────────────┘

☣ Warning ☣
pl.len() is currently an unsigned int (but may change in the future)
We cast to an integer to avoid potential issues with overflow.
df.group_by("group").agg(int = 2 - pl.len().cast(int), uint32 = 2 - pl.len())

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ int ┆ uint32     │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ u32        │
╞═══════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ a     ┆ -1  ┆ 4294967295 │ # <- pl.repeat(None, 4294967295) would be bad.
│ b     ┆ 0   ┆ 0          │
│ c     ┆ 1   ┆ 1          │
└───────┴─────┴────────────┘


.clip() can also be used to enforce lower/upper bounds.



https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17722


If you change the pl.col('value') to pl.exclude('group') and the explode("value") to explode(pl.exclude('group') then it ought to work for any number of "value" columns without being hard coded to a column name.

You can solve this using groupby to group the df by the group column.
Then pad each group with NULL values if a group <= 4 , then we concatenate all group after process it with pl.concat.
Here is a code snippet to guide you.
ef make_groups_uniform(df, group_by, group_size):
    def padding_each_group(group: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
        missing_data_count = group_size - group.shape[0]
        if missing_data_count > 0:
            # missing values
            missing_df = pl.DataFrame(
                {
                    group_by: [group[group_by][0]]
                    * missing_data_count,  # Fill with the group value
                    "value": [None] * missing_data_count,  # Fill with None
                }
            )
            # Concatenate the original group with the missing DataFrame
            group = pl.concat([group, missing_df])
        return group

    # Collect each group as separate DataFrames
    groups = []
    for _, df_group in df.group_by(group_by, maintain_order=True):
        padded_group = padding_each_group(df_group)
        groups.append(padded_group)

    # concat all groups
    output = pl.concat(groups)

    return output


print(output)
shape: (12, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    │
│ a     ┆ a2    │
│ a     ┆ a3    │
│ a     ┆ null  │
│ b     ┆ b1    │
│ …     ┆ …     │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ c1    │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘```


You can find the largest group using .group_by().len().max(), then groupby and convert each value in the groups to a struct, unnest the struct using a 'max_width' strategy, then unpivot the wide data.  After that you can pad up to the difference between the largest group and the desired group size.
def make_groups_uniform(df: pl.DataFrame, group_by: str, value_col: str, group_size: int):
    gb = df.group_by(group_by)
    largest_group_size = gb.len().max()['len'].item()
    out = gb.all().with_columns(
        pl.col(value_col)
          .list
          .to_struct(n_field_strategy='max_width')
    ).unnest(
         value_col
    ).unpivot(index=group_by, value_name=value_col)[[group_by, value_col]]
    n = group_size - largest_group_size

    if n > 0:
        keys = df[group_by].unique().to_list()
        pad = pl.DataFrame({group_by: keys * n, value_col: ['null']*n*len(keys)})
        out = pl.concat([out, pad])
    return out.sort(group_by)

Running the code:
make_groups_uniform(dfa, 'group', 'value', 4)
# returns:
shape: (12, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ a1    │
│ a     ┆ a2    │
│ a     ┆ a3    │
│ a     ┆ null  │
│ b     ┆ b1    │
│ …     ┆ …     │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ c1    │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
│ c     ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘

